# 6 pin vs 9 pin switches

Tags: switches, pins

So I currently have a 9 pin switch, that looks like this: 
[image]

And the project I'm doing calls for a 6 pin switch like this: 
[image]

I'm kind of an electronics newbie and I was wondering if I could just use the 9 pin switch instead of the 6 pin. Would it be a massive problem and is not possible at all or could it work out?

All advice is appreciated, thanks for everything. :D

Here's the schematic: [image]

Comment: Do you happen to have datasheets for both of these that you could link to? The connectors are different; would that pose a problem for you even if the switches can be made to be functionally identical?

Comment: Here are the links to them, I hope it helps: http://www.amazon.com/Sonline-6Pins-Momentary-Switch-Guitar/dp/B00X9HXFEO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1433460093&sr=8-1&keywords=6+pin+switch+foot

Comment: The other one: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GWCTWO0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_search_detailpage

Comment: What are you planning to use it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DPDT switch is momentary, while the 3PDT switch appears to be alternate-action, so they're not compatible in terms of physical actuation.

From your schematic there's no electrical toggling going on, so you'll need an alternate-action switch, wired like this:[image]

Comment: Yep, missed that bit.

Comment: So the 6 pin won't stay in place? It won't keep the circuit running after pressure is released ?

Comment: @HLatfullin: Correct.

Comment: @HLatfullin: From the switch's point of view, that's right.  However, your project may have circuitry which toggles every time the switch is pressed, so it's impossible to say for sure without a schematic.

Comment: I put the schematic there now

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum you should beg or borrow some kind of *continuity tester* that can confirm which connectors on the switches are electrically connected in each (usually 2, sometimes 3) mechanical state. A continuity tester can be a VOM set to measure resistance, a battery and a light bulb, or a battery and a buzzer. You need to identify which pairs of connectors are "normally open" or "normally closed" since this characterises a switch's function. The other electrical characteristic of a switch is its maximum voltage and current ratings that should not be exceeded; you have to find where these are specified because you cannot measure them. It would be dangerous to use a switch intended for a low-current low voltage circuit in a mains voltage power circuit.